# Is there an option to roll back on Parse?

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I modified the code and I want to rollback, any chance to do? I need to restore it 6 months ago although there are no real changes and the code is minimal.

Comment: Are  you talking about cloud-code?

Answer (score 0):

It's simply `parse rollback -r v2` to rollback to version 2 for instance. Keep in mind that the files corresponding to version 2 will not be automatically updated on your computer.